# Compilation errors when using cout

Tags: c++

I have compilation errors to just simply output a `cout` message. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char letter = 'a';
    short age = 10;
    int cout = 575;
    long numStars = 985632145;
    float pi = 3.1;
    double price = 89.65;
    string season = "summer";

    cout << "Letter: "<< letter << endl;
    std::cout << "Age: " << age<< endl;
    std::cout << "Cout: " << cout << endl;
    std::cout << "Number Stars: " << numStars << endl;
    std::cout << "Pi: " << pi << endl;
    std::cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
    std::cout << "Season: " << season;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are on the line:

```
cout << "Letter: "<< letter << endl;
```

I have tried reinstalling VS2015 but that didn't help.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to provide a [mcve] and include the exact error messages you get (as text, *not* as screenshot).

Comment: Strongly consider giving [ask] a read over as well.

Comment: _What_ compilation errors? What's the minimal amount of code you need to reproduce this? No one can help otherwise as there are a plethora of reasons you may be getting errors

Comment: Well I new to this web page, sorry I can't express the question well. The thing is that VS2015 isn't building properly a simple c++ program of display types of variables i.e, char, int, long, double, float. The problem is using the namespace std. cout << "Letter"  is a message and that's my problem VS sends me an error where it says "Letter"

Comment: Found a temporary solution and that was to change the projects' properties and where it says 'Character Set' I changed the multibyte Character Set to Unicode Character Set. And the errors disappeared!

Comment: @AlexEnginner If you've found a solution, post it as an answer :) Then after 2 days you will be able to accept it as _the answer_ if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variable of type `int` called `cout` - this is not allowed given that you are `using namespace std`. Change this variable name to something else, and avoid the statement [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

`std::cout` is a "reserved type/keyword" so you cannot use it as a variable name.

Comment: I don't recall `cout` being reserved and nothing I've seen in a quick looksie says it is, but the rest of this answer is spot on.